# Is there any meaning, in terms of performance by using unnecessary using \ imports declarations

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

McCarson.LearningToCode.Week(3);

`Adding to give context to set experience expectations`

I have seen developers import references on the code behind for very specific elements within a library as well as import references for the entire library itself irrelevant of whatever the needed element is.  How much memory is conserved (if any) with the specific element needed being referenced for the page, to the point that, is it considered best practice to only import the needed element or is it a trivial concern? (I did see that it marginalizes room for error)

`I researched MSDN, did not find the answer so asking here seems like a logical choice`

Comment: unnecessary imports are in light gray. The one you need to keep will be black. You can also right click on your import and select remove unnecessary imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be negligible to make `using` / `imports`when there is no need **but** it can also harm performance (depends on your program and the referenced assembly size and hypersensitivity to performance) and its a bad programming habit.
the meaning of every `using` / `imports` statement is that the compiler will search properties / methods / classes etc within that assembly. also you must take into account the order of the `using` statements - the compiler will search according to the order of the using statements.

BTW - there is a small difference between VB.NET and C# - VB imports the major namespaces by default opposed to C#.
by saying major namespaces (.net framework 4.6):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

and as @Chillzy wrote in his comment VS will color
unnecessary imports in dark gray.

Comment: Thank you so much as well as to @Chillzy && @Christopher. I believe that comments at stackoverflow should be extended to appreciation (in addition to clarity) for the help received to those that provide help   `deverence();`

Answer (score 2):

Using/Importing is first a shorthand to avoid having to use fully qualified type names (Namespace + Classname).

There might be performance considerations too, but only while **writing** the code - not at runtime. Regardless how you write your code, the IL will still use a fully qualified typename. If you do not give a fully qualified name, Compiler and Intellisense kind of have to "guess" in wich used namespace the class you reference resides. Wich 95% of the cases works without any issues.

Using/Importing whole namespaces can have issues from a Ambiguity point of view. For example, there are at least 3 Namespaces with a "Timer" class. Each of them is a different type, with different bebavior and different Proeprties/Events.

If you using/import any two of those Namesapces, the classname "Timer" is no longer ambigious like "string" or "object" is. So all of a sudden, you have to use the fully qualified name for all Timer instances once again.

So in very rare circumstances, using/importing the whole namespace on a global level will cause you no end of issues. Hence it can be preferable to limit both the scope and the depth of a use/include directive.